Drilled anchor holes in drywall far enough to hit metal on external wall, concerned about moisture getting in
Was trying to hang a curtain rod but hit metal on external wall. Super sensitive to mold and worried moisture will now come in.
What do I do? Is latex caulk or spackling enough to seal off potential moisture? Which one is better for this situation/airtight?

what would be your question if you did not hit metal?
